# Golang в спортивном программировании

Tags: c++, c, golang, олимпиада

Немного увлекаюсь спортивным программированием (решаю задачи на codeforces, leetcode, acmp). Недавно познакомился с языком C, в целом, программировать на нем уже в состоянии. 50% от цели изучения C - решать задачи через быстрый C, а не через медленный Python (например, на codeforces задачи A решаются нормально, а далее становится трудно (для меня) уложится по времени (не во всех задачах)). Но скорость решения этих задач упала в разы. Отсутствие строк, нормальных встроенных функций, отладка. Заинтересовался языком Golang, он же Go. Все пишут, что он простой, мощный, быстрый. Но никто не писал про его уместность в спортивном программировании. Конкурентоспособен ли этот язык в этом направлении, или, все же, идти через стандартные C и C++

Comment: Go больше нацелен на веб, он как раз таки решает проблему того, что писать веб на C это сплошная боль. Скорее всего больше существующих решений и подходов вы найдёте в C, так как Go относительно новый. Я бы остановил свой выбор всё таки на c/c++

Comment: те, кто пишет, что он простой - глупцы. разве что hello world писали.
я решал задачи в hackerrank medium и выше сложности. между go, java и плюсов разницы не увидел. разве что на плюсах придумали 3 разные решение простой задачи массивы

Comment: Вам нужен язык простой, быстрый и универсальный? Запросто, но только два из трех!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Многие думают, что существует мифический язык Х, который приведет их в топы любых соревнований. Но [Серебряной пули](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_bullet) не существует.

Все задачи на соревновательных платформах можно грубо поделить на 4 типа.

- тренировочные задачи. Их можно решать на любом языке, ошибиться в них почти невозможно, главная их цель - научится работать с платфорой.
- обычные задачи. Такие задачи легко пишутся на питоне/java, но иногда бывает не хватает чуточку скорости. На с/с++ пишутся иногда чуточку сложнее, но иногда даже в лоб написанный код успевает вовремя.
- сложные задачи. Здесь уже с/с++ втискивается в время только с разными трюками, но и то не всегда. python/java тут напрягается, если решать задачу в лоб. Поэтому, в большинстве случаев эти задачи решаются за счет поиска более красивого алгоритма.

  Например, рассмотрим простую задачу - найти сумму чисел от a до b. Обычный подход заключается просто в обычном цикле. Но если a и b очень большие числе, то тут никакой язык не поможет (хотя clang  в некоторых случаях может удивить - если он догадается, что это сумма чисел). Но как только вспоминается школьная формула сумма ряда (да, я знаю, что многие считают, что им школьная математика не нужна совсем, но они пишут другие задачи, например, через браузер процессор подогревает:) ). Через известную формулу сумма ряда считается за константное время (сложили, умножили, поделили попалам), вместо O(n).

  В этой таких задачах практически не имеет значения язык, даже на написаному в ручную интерпретаторе бейсика на ардуинке можно вложится в время, если знать/найти подходящий алгоритм, а на большом кластере с тысячами процессоров считать годами с вылизанным кодом на ассемблере.
- и последний тип задач - это задачи, для которых не существует (не найдено) хорошего алгоритма. Например, разложение на множители. И тут в ход идут всякие трюки и ухищрения, что бы хоть как то уложится.

Вывод. Если хочется выйти в топ соревновательных сайтов, не ищите "идеальный язык". Читайте Кнута, Кормена, Седжвика.

Если просто хочется прокачатся в языке, тогда решайте задачи на том языке, на котором хотите дальше продолжать. Узнаете разные хорошие вещи о своем языке. Я так один раз решил пойти работать как perl разработчик и где то месяц решал задачи на таких сайтах, но на perl. И на интервью я легко отвечал на разные мелкие каверзные вопросы.

Comment: Я знаю, что выход в топ не зависит от выбранного яп. Понятно, что каждый выбирает тот язык, который ему по душе, но тот же JavaScript явно неуместен в рамках codeforces на задачах уровня B, C и т.д. Вопрос был именно про уместность языка, то есть может ли он конкурировать, с той же самой Java, например. Конкурировать в плане скорости написания программы и эффективности алгоритмов, скорости там

Comment: я думаю, что в умелых руках, даже javascript может быть в топе. На подобных соревнованиях очень мало (думаю их нет) задач, которые рассчитаны на то, что бы взять скоростью генерируемого кода.

Comment: ну, скорее всего действительно на моем уровне нет смысла рассуждать подходит язык или не подходит для спортивного программирования. На чем нравится - на том и буду решать. В любом случае, спасибо за ответ

Comment: берите любой популярный язык - python, golang, java, c/c++, javascript, а может даже rust/ruby/perl/haskell (то есть, тот язык, который востребован на рынке, может даже php) и практикуйтесь на нем - и будет класно

Answer (score -2):

На ваш вопрос невозможно дать разумный ответ. Что такое "конкуретоспособность" и "спортивное программирование"? Какие фичи требуются от языка?

Посмотрите [сравнение C++ и Go](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/fastest/go-gpp.html). Go медленнее C++ от полутора до 10 раз. В зависимости от задачи. Это много или мало?

На том же сайте [сравнение Go и Python](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/fastest/go-python3.html). В каких-то задачах Go быстрее в 200 раз, а в каких-то наравне с Python. Опять таки, можно ли по этим данным судить о конкурентоспособности этих языков?

Что-то определённое можно сказать только про сравнение [Go и Java](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/fastest/go.html): программы на этих языках выполняются примерно за одинаковое время.

Comment: Конкурентоспособность в плане решения задач и времени на решение этих задач. Например, вы привели пример: Java. Язык Java использовал Petr - один из топовых прогеров на codeforces, соответственно, Java конкурентоспособен. Я не говорю о том, что о конкурентоспособности говорит человек, который его использует. Я пытаюсь узнать об именно использовании, преимуществах этого языка в спортивном программировании

Comment: @Pak маленькая ремарка. Java нужен разогрев перед выполнением, тогда она выполняется также как го(почти)

Comment: @SeniorPomidor в `The Computer Language Benchmarks Game` они запускают Java без разогрева/раскачки. Просто как `java -cp . MainClass`. Именно в таком сценарии Java выполняется практически как Golang. Получается, что Java машина в целом более эффективна, чем Golang runtime, так как за то же время в Java успевают не только выполнить бизнес логику, но и рапарсить байт код, и прогнать JIT компилятор.

Comment: @CameUp ну вот вам и ответ: Go конкурентоспособен настолько же, насколько Java. Если Java подходит для спортивного программирования, то и Go тоже подойдёт. Хотя если бы меня поставили перед выбором Go vs Java, то я бы выбрал Java. На крайний случай C#. Go я бы выбирал только от безнадёги. На всех этих языках я написал не одну тысячу строк, поэтому могу выбирать и сравнивать. Мой выбор - Java.